# Unbiased variance question

Tags: self-study, variance

A researcher is testing if a new swimming technique is more effective. She knows the average 50m time of swimmers in her club using the old technique is 35 seconds. After training 12 swimmers with the new technique she times them over 50m and summarises their time (t) in seconds:

sigma (t) = 399

Sigma (t^2) = 13305

Lower times are considered better in swimming.

Show that the unbiased estimate of the variance is 3.48 to two decimal places:

Very unsure of how to do this, I thought the answer was 3.19. I got this through E(X^2) - (E(X))^2

and E(X^2) = 1108.75 and E(X) = 33.25.

How do you get 3.48?

Comment: I've added the self-study tag Sam. You might want to read up on that.

Comment: I've just always thought the way to get Var(X) is by = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2, how does the 3.48 value come about?

Comment: You get 3.48 by applying the correct formula.  It looks like you divided by $n=12$ rather than $n-1=11$ at a crucial juncture.

Comment: I'm confused, so how do I get 3.48? 1108.75/12 - (33.25/11)^2?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose data are $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_{12}$ and let
$A = \sum_{i=1}^{12} T_i$ and $B = \sum_{i=1}^{12} T_i^2.$
Then the *sample* mean $\bar T = A/12 = 33.25$ and the *sample*
variance is 
$$S_T^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (T_i - \bar T)^2}{n-1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{12} (T_i - \bar T)^2}{11} \\
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{12} T_i^2 - \frac 1 n (\sum_{i-1}^n T_i)^2}{n-1}= 
\frac{B  - A^2/12}{11},$$

where the second line is sometimes called the 'computational formula' for this *sample* variance.
Can you find that formula in your textbook or class notes?

Using R as a calculator:

```
A = 399;  B = 13305
(1/11)*(B - A^2/12)
## 3.477273
```

*Note:* By contrast, if $X$ is a random variable with $\mu_X = E(X),$ then its (population) variance is
$$\sigma_X^2 = E(X - \mu_X)^2 = E(X^2) - \mu_X^2.$$
It seems you are confusing the two kinds of variances and their formulas. You wouldn't be the first
statistics student to do this, but *now* is the time
to read carefully and sort out the difference.